# Border of child element affects div size of the parent

Tags: html, css

I made it so that when I hover a item in my menu, there comes a little line underneath it with: `border-bottom: 2px;`. Now when I hover the item in my menu the parent element (The header in this case) will also grow `2px` on the bottom.

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="header"> 

    <nav class="navigation_menu">

            <ul class="navigation_ul">

                <a href="#"><li>Lorum</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Ipsum</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Lorpsum</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Ipum</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Nadoa</li></a>

            </ul>

    </nav>

</div>
```

**My CSS code:**

```
body {
    background:f5f5f5;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: roboto;
}

/** Text Style **/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

/** Header Style **/

.header {
    background: #607d8b;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    color: white;
}

/** Navigation Menu Style **/

.navigation_menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation_menu li {
    font-size:18px;
}

.navigation_menu li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.navigation_menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

**And here is a sample:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVjJqW

I hope I can find some answer here! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the border occupies some space, so the parent grows.

Instead, you can consider setting a transparent border and changing the color at hover:

```css
.navigation_menu li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.navigation_menu li:hover {
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```css
/** General Style **/
body {
  background: f5f5f5;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: roboto;
}

/** Text Style **/
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

/** Header Style **/
.header {
  background: #607d8b;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: white;
}

/** Navigation Menu Style **/
.navigation_menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation_menu li {
  font-size:18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.navigation_menu li:hover {
  border-bottom-color: white;
}
.navigation_menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <nav class="navigation_menu">
    <ul class="navigation_ul">
      <a href="#"><li>Lorum</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Ipsum</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Lorpsum</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Ipum</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Nadoa</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution-

For `.navigation_menu li:hover`, add `margin-bottom: -2px;`, and remove the `overflow: hidden;` for `ul`

Answer (score 0):

add `.navigation_menu li` - `border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;`

```css
/** General Style **/

body {
 background:f5f5f5;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: roboto;
}

/** Text Style **/

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

/** Header Style **/

.header {
 background: #607d8b;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 color: white;
}

/** Navigation Menu Style **/

.navigation_menu ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation_menu li {
 font-size:18px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.navigation_menu li:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.navigation_menu ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
 
  <nav class="navigation_menu">
    
    <ul class="navigation_ul">
     
     <a href="#"><li>Lorum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Ipsum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Lorpsum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Ipum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Nadoa</li></a>
    
    </ul>
  
  </nav>
  
 </div>
```

use pseudo-elements  `:before` or `:after`

```css
/** General Style **/

body {
 background:f5f5f5;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: roboto;
}

/** Text Style **/

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}

/** Header Style **/

.header {
 background: #607d8b;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 color: white;
}

/** Navigation Menu Style **/

.navigation_menu ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation_menu li {
 font-size:18px;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation_menu li:hover:before {
 content: '';
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;       
}



.navigation_menu ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
 
  <nav class="navigation_menu">
    
    <ul class="navigation_ul">
     
     <a href="#"><li>Lorum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Ipsum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Lorpsum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Ipum</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li>Nadoa</li></a>
    
    </ul>
  
  </nav>
  
 </div>
```